# how to get volume unit(vU) from peak power of avrecorder?

Tags: iphone

someone can help me for how to calculate the vU by using peak power [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0] value. also describe the diff b/w RMS and vU because i am very confused.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

RMS is average voltage/power (on sinusoid typicaly square root of 2 multiplied by peak voltage).
You can not calculate peak voltage from wattage, since wattage is complimentary U*I.

Comment: i need to display vU value (-20 to +3) like voice memo. how can i get by peak value, any other alternative for it..

Comment: these vU metters usualy have logarithmic dB scale. Read here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel